# Added UseHsts in Blazor application but Strict Transport Security isn't working for Blazor Maui

Tags: http-headers, blazor, maui, hsts, strict-transport-security

My issue is when the Strict Transport Security header is added, the Maui application won't load, it is stuck on 'Authorizing...'

I've added HTTP headers within the API program.cs using Middleware and I've also added the `app.UseHsts();` with the configuration below.
I have also tried adding the header manually with the other headers in the Middleware but that also doesn't work.

I added the `ExcludeHosts.Clear()` to make it work with localhost, I've also tried adding the Host of the Maui app.

Is there a way around this or a way to remove the Strict Transport Security header for Maui but not for Wasm?

```
builder.Services.AddHsts(options =>
{
    options.ExcludedHosts.Clear();
    options.ExcludedHosts.Add("http://0.0.0.0/");
    options.Preload = true;
    options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
    options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(730);
});
```

Comment: I can't add `app.UseHsts();` in the maui blazor project. Can you show the details about reproducing the problem?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, the http headers and `app.UseHsts()` is all setup on the Server (API) within a middleware. When I'm using Blazor Wasm everything works but switching to Maui doesn't. I thought it was because I was adding headers but after investigating I got it working with headers except for the Strict Transport Security header. So the issue is the header not the `app.UseHsts()`

Comment: Did you test it on all the platforms?

Comment: I tested it in Chrome using Wasm and Windows using Maui. Haven't tested on Android and iOS yet, but we need it working for windows anyway.

Comment: This should be the webview's limit. In the maui, the razor page shows in the webview not the browser.